# Linkedin API get names of organizations of authenticated user

Tags: curl, linkedin-api

I'm trying to use the LinkedIn API to retrieve the names of organizations where the authenticated user is an administrator.

I tried to call the endpoint route provided by the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/organizations/organization-access-control-by-role?view=li-lms-2024-02&tabs=http#sample-request-3):

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationAcls?q=roleAssignee&role=ADMINISTRATOR&projection=(elements%5C*(%5C*,organization%5C~(localizedName)))
```

But I got the error:
`{"status":400,"code":"ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT","message":"projection parameter is not allowed for this endpoint"}`

Is there an alternative solution to get the organization names without calling the `GET /organizations/{id}` endpoint individually for each organization after retrieving their ids ?